# Integration of dialogflow agent with google assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ektpe.png)As from 12 June conversational google actions are depreciated so I cant integrate my Dialogflow agent with assistant there is any other way to integrate Dialogflow agent with google action for use it on google assistant app?

I created Dialogflow agent and try to integrate with assistant but as there is message Dialogflow depreciating assistant integration so I cant integrate it giving error page there is any new way for integration ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, This will be no more supported. Here is blog post. https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset#what_is_being_removed

The reason behind that is to make assistant to more connected with apps, so you use alternative option with apps. but only if your business have apps and user have it in the device.

https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/06/Helping-Developers-Create-Meaningful-Voice-Interactions-with-Android.html